# Append a dataframe to the bottom of another dataframe within a dictionary of dataframes Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to add a dataframe to the bottom to the first dataframe that is in a dictionary of dataframes.

Both dataframes have the same structure.

```
#d is the dictionary of dataframes
#df_new is the name of the dataframe wanting to add to the bottom of the first datafrmae in #the dictionary of dataframes 
d.items[0] = df.items[0].append(df_new,ignore_index = True)
```

I get the following error
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: pls share reproducible code and structure of varliables like `d` , Check-https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
list(d.values())[0] = [list(d.values())[0],df_new]
```